# How to run FaceBook Style Image Editing jQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery

i found script on net here [FaceBook Style Image Editing jQuery Plugin](http://netindonesia.net/blogs/cipto/archive/2009/10/24/jquery-plugin-edit-image-facebook-style.aspx) but it seem's to be not work

here is my code test.html :

**//calling a jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/app/js/jquery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js">
```

**//calling a css**

```
<style type="text/css">
 //css code that obtain from website
<style>
```

**//calling a js app**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//js code that is obtained from website
</script>
```

**//calling a application**

```
</script>
    $('#albump').editFaceBook();        
</script>
```

**//adding image**

```
<img id ="albump" src="http://localhost/app/imgs/album.gif">
```

**Is some thing i am doing wrong ? or this code is wrong ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this is ready function

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/app/js/jquery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js">
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#albump").editFaceBook();
    });
   <script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the second line of the documentation link you posted - it works on `<div>`'s only.  Wrap your image in a div and call the plugin on that:

```
<div id="albump">
    <img src="http://localhost/app/imgs/album.gif" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#albump").editFacebook();
</script>
```

Comment: try putting the script inside document.ready in the head of your page:  `$(document).ready(function(){$("#albump").editFaceBook();});`